# Python 3.5 with OpenSSL v > 1 MAC OSX Mojave

Tags: python, macos, openssl

Openssl version of my mac and the python is not same. 
Openssl version of my mac is as following:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
```

Where when i check it in python `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION` I'm getting the following version:
`'OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016'`

I've tried brew but it's installing `python 3.7` but I need 3.5. Tried installing it with pyenv but no luck, same version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally after a long research, I've found the best way to solve it. You cannot resolve it with the `brew install python` just because it will install the latest python available. To install the specified version of the python you have to use [homebrew-python](https://github.com/sashkab/homebrew-python). For example for python 3.5 you can install it like this:

`brew install sashkab/python/python35`

From their github page currently they have the following versions:

```
+----------------+-----------------+
| Python Version | Latest revision |
+----------------+-----------------+
| Python 2.7     | 2.7.15          |
| Python 3.5     | 3.5.6           |
| Python 3.6     | 3.6.8           |
| Python 3.7     | 3.7.2           |
+----------------+-----------------+
```

For some of you guys this may not work as on macos you should have proper CLI tools for this refer to [this issue](https://github.com/sashkab/homebrew-python/issues/29).

After all this make you virtual enviorment with `python3.5` under the following directory on macos:

`/usr/local/opt/python35/bin/python3.5`

Try running the following commands in your python console to test the openssl version:

```
import ssl;
ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
```

You'll get the v1 of OpenSSL. Which can also helps you to resolve the painfull **Connection reset by peer** issue too.